# How to save value in html input text

Tags: php, html

I have form with input text and this form action direct to the same page,
now i insert string into input text like "air garden" then submit but after that string in input text become one word that mean it show only "air" not "air garden".

```
<input type="text" id="sfo_keywords" <?php if($sfo_array['sfo_keywords']) echo "value=".$sfo_array['sfo_keywords'];?> />
```

Comment: So you are trying to get the first word in a string? "Tiger Prawn" would become "Tiger" for example. Or "PHP Manual rocks" would be just "PHP"?

Answer (score 4):

This is because you're appending directly to the `value=` without extra quotes, then in your html code you have something like

```
<input type="text" value=air garden />
```

instead of:

```
<input type="text" value="air garden" />
```

You can to that to fix it :

```
<input type="text" id="sfo_keywords" <?php if($sfo_array['sfo_keywords']) echo "value=\"".$sfo_array['sfo_keywords']."\"";?> />
```

Comment: What the hell!? LOL. You answer two minutes after me with the same explanation and you obtain the upvote? Each day I understand less this community.

Comment: However, my upvote to you too. You can do the same ;)

Comment: Thank you very much now i understood :)

Comment: @M.Ahmed you need to choose the correct answer clicking the check at the left side of them.

Answer (score 3):

You've missed the quotes:

```
<input type="text" id="sfo_keywords" 
       <?php if($sfo_array['sfo_keywords']) {
                echo "value='".$sfo_array['sfo_keywords'];."'";
             }
       ?>  
/>
```

If you don't wrap the values of the attributes into quotes only the first occurrence will be rendered, and next will be considered attributes.

Example:

```
 <input class="one two">
```

Or

```
 <input class=one two> <!-- here you are the "two" attribute-->
```